# Word VSTO Font.Hidden = 1 doesn't work as documented

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I have following text in a Word document : "123". I created a style that has Font Hidden checked. I apply the style to '2' in that text. I want to hide this text 123 using add-in so I set

```
MyRange.Font.Hidden = 1;
```

But then 1 and 3 is hidden and 2 is unhidden ? 2 is toggled. How do I hide it completely ? Note that I don't want to go character by character and inspect if it is hidden or not and hide it only if it is not hidden because I have a large document.

Comment: The documented legal values for the property setter are True, False and wdToggle.  True equals -1 in COM interop, not 1.

Comment: @Hans Passant - thank you. I tried that with -1 and it still toggles the text where the style was applied. What's interesting is that it toggles it only if it is hidden but once it makes it visible, there's absolutely no effect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Word has the concept of "toggle properties". If such a property is set in the style hierarchy, it just toggles the current state. Toggle properties are e.g. bold and italic, but also hidden. This means that the behavior you observe is standard Word application behavior.

A solution could be to apply the same style that is already applied to the text "2" to the entire text instead of using direct formatting:

```
MyRange.Style = MyRange.Document.Styles.get_Item("MyHiddenStyle");
```